# Calculate Given Number on a Method Gives This Error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this method :

```
- (void) voteResult: (NSString *)partyName votedNumber:(int)votedNumber
{
    int *moreVotes;
    moreVotes = 2000 - votedNumber;

    _labelVoteResult.text = @"Currently, your party (%x) has %i votes. We need %i more votes to put %x on our list. Share to your Facebook or Twitter to get more votes from your downline or upline.", partyName, votedNumber, moreVotes, partyName;
}
```

but I got this error message :

```
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'int *' from 'int'
```

because of this line :

```
moreVotes = 2000 - votedNumber;
```

also I have this error message too :

```
Expression result unused
```

because of this line (`partyName`) :

```
_labelVoteResult.text = @"Currently, your party (%x) has %i votes. We need %i more votes to put %x on our list. Share to your Facebook or Twitter to get more votes from your downline or upline.", partyName, votedNumber, moreVotes, partyName;
```

and last thing, %x should be a string, but Objective C only have %i for integer, %c for char. I have no idea what is exactly for a string.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method should look like this:

```
- (void) voteResult: (NSString *)partyName votedNumber:(int)votedNumber
{
    // Not int*
    int moreVotes = 2000 - votedNumber;

    // Use [NSString stringWithFormat:] with partyName using the %@ format specifier
    _labelVoteResult.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Currently, your party (%@) has %i votes. We need %i more votes to put %@ on our list. Share to your Facebook or Twitter to get more votes from your downline or upline.", partyName, votedNumber, moreVotes, partyName);

}
```